# How to read the below sample XML and insert two separate entry for each employee in PostgreSQL using AWS Glue - Apache PySpark

Tags: aws-glue

How to read the below sample XML and insert 2 separate entry for each employee in PostgreSQL using AWS Glue - Apache PySpark.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<details>
    <OrganizationName>XXX</OrganizationName>
    <Employee>
        <name>aaa</name>
        <designation>YY</designation>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <name>bbb</name>
        <designation>YY</designation>
    </Employee>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [custom XML classifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-xml) with row tag 'Employee'.

Comment: Thank for your reply!!. I did try the approach which u suggested. It is creating entries with only name and designation. But the requirement was to have an entry with organizationName, name and designation for each employee. Could you please provide a workaround for it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: In that case instead of custom classifier you should work with <details> as a single entry and then use [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#explode) function and then select required fields from nested object (select('OrganizationName', 'Employee.name', 'Employee. designation'))